# Flutter Google Map, how to merge two different marker list?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

```
    GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: geocode!,
          zoom: 14,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          googleMapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);
        },
        compassEnabled: true,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        onTap: (v) {},
        markers: <--->),

        ------
        List<Marker> dumA = [];
        markerGroupA = Set<Marker>.of(dumA);
        List<Marker> dumB = [];
        markerGroupB = Set<Marker>.of(dumB);
```

I have a list of these two marker groups. How can I display them on `markers:` ? I don't want to put them into one `Set<Marker>` if possible. I was able to do that but I lost the code and can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set<T>` has a method `union` that merges 2 Sets.
You can find the dart documentation here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set/union.html

```dart
GoogleMap(
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: geocode!,
    zoom: 14,
  ),
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
    googleMapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);
  },
  compassEnabled: true,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  onTap: (v) {},
  markers: markerGroupA.union(markerGroupB),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addAll function as below

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: geocode!,
          zoom: 14,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          googleMapControllerCompleter.complete(controller);
        },
        compassEnabled: true,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        onTap: (v) {},
        markers: markerGroupA),

        ------
        List<Marker> dumA = [];
        markerGroupA = Set<Marker>.of(dumA);
        List<Marker> dumB = [];
        markerGroupB = Set<Marker>.of(dumB);
        markerGroupA.addAll(markerGroupB);
```